# Do std::async and std::future scale well on iOS and Android platforms?

Tags: android, c++, ios, c++11, stdasync

I have a 2D particle system for a game engine in which I want to decouple the update loop of the particles from the main thread.  I am using a thread pool implemented with boost::asio and am splitting up all the tasks into several stages and then combining the results on the main thread.  This works well for me, and guarantees a limit on the total threads I have allowed for the pool (which is shared by all particle emitters which fire their own tasks independently).

I have read a lot of articles discussing std::async and std::future.  This seems to be totally reasonable on windows or linux type systems where thread creation is well managed by the OS and memory is bountiful. But it seems like very little focus is spent on discussing this kind of thing in a mobile platform where thread creation may be costly.  Because I am not sure how many threads might be made on these platforms it seems hard to rely on std::async in contexts where I don't know how many async calls may be in action at a given time (if each creates its own thread).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2

I would like to hear from an individual with multithreaded C++ mobile development experience.  My question in summary is this:

If I create 20 particle effects, each with 4 concurrent async tasks, will this result in 100 threads each taking .5 mb of ram?  Or does async have some magic support for being intelligent with thread creation and task sharing?

Alternatively will async bog down the main thread (if not being explicit with the thread creation rule) effectively lagging my gameplay for relatively low-priority particle effects?

If so, what context is async **actually** useful in on mobile as it seems thread creation is something you'd like to be a little more explicit about on these devices.

Comment: Can I ask why wouldn't you just spin up one thread and dedicate that thread to updating all particle systems that are alive at any one time?

Comment: I suppose I could do that as well, except if I have idle processors I don't mind throwing 1 to 4 threads at it to update more smoothly.  It's this kind of thing that a thread pool helps with, and that's why I'm using one right now.  Phones have 2 to 8 cores nowadays, having only 1 dedicated particle thread isn't as scalable as creating a thread pool with 1 to 4 threads for low priority tasks.  I'm not a concurrency wizard either, so maybe this whole question is silly.  But my async query stands.

Comment: But this gets to the thrust of my question: lots of articles talk about using async, how viable is this advice for mobile?

Comment: I consider `future` and `async` and `thread` to be primitives.  They should be treated like calling `new` directly in client code: sure, quick to write, but not something you want to do all over the place in production code.  What they provide is standardized access to the possibility of multi threading more than anything.  Wrap them in a higher level abstraction!  Write a threadpool with `std::future`s produced by `std::promises` fullfilled by your worker threads.  Return deferred `std::future`s that notice when a threadpool task is waiting on them, and kick off the producing task.

Comment: Yakk, if you make that comment an answer, and maybe provide a reference or two for further reading I'll accept that answer.

Comment: Async doesn't have to produce a new thread. So, with a decent compiler, you shouldn't end up with more threads than the system can handle and are actually beneficial for performance (e.g. equal to the number of cores). Unfortunately I don't have experience with iOS or Android, so i can't tell you what actual implementations will do.